# Passing alias as function argument linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, bash-function

Hi everyone I'm learning how to use the .bashrc file in linux and as my title states I'm wondering how to make a function recognize an argument as an alias

I have an alias called home defined as: `alias home=$HOME`

and a function go defined as

```
function go(){
cd $1
ls $1
}
```

but when I do `go home`
i get

`bash: cd: home: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access home: No such file or directory`

when I want it to do go $HOME

how would i go about implementing this?

Comment: Can you just do `go $HOME`?

Comment: Or simply `cd` with no argument at all?

Comment: @GregHewgill It would be `cd && ls` to get the above example :)

Comment: `alias home="cd && ls"` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alias is not a word substitution but a small newly created command:

```
$ alias bla=ls
$ bla
file1
file2
file3
…
```

So, it cannot be used in the way you assumed.

You might want to use variable substitution for this:

```
$ home=$HOME
$ function go() {
  cd "$(eval echo \$"$1")"
}
$ go home
```

In case you want to use an alias despite that this is an abuse, try this:

```
$ alias home=$HOME
$ function go() {
  cd "$(type "$1" | sed -e 's/.*is aliased to .//' -e 's/.$//')"
}
$ go home
```

Comment: +1. you can use [variable indirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in bash: `go() { cd "${!1}"; }; go home`

Answer (score 4):

> I'm wondering how to make a function recognize an argument as an alias

To answer your question literally, you could use [`type -t`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-type) inside your function to determine whether its argument is an alias.  But that's probably not what you want.

AFAIK, what you actually want isn't possible.  From the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) (emphasis mine):

> Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word **when it is used as the first word** of a simple command.

The closest you could get is:

```
go `home`
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was extremely helpful (especially the link) however @Alfe made it work though slightly changed. But +1 for the answer still =D